# How to solve FTP Error 2 Not a Directory

Tags: python, ftp

I am using the below code for downloading files from a ftp server.But I am getting an error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory:`, but the file present in the server and I can able download it via terminal. Can anyone help me!!

```
import ftplib
import os
remotpath='folder/subfolder'
try:
   ftpclient = ftplib.FTP('ftp.xxxx.com')
   ftpclient.login('user', 'pass')
   ftpclient.cwd(remotpath)
   print "login succeessfull"
   files = ftpclient.nlst()
   for eachFile in files:
       saveTo = os.path.join(remotpath,eachFile)
       if (not os.path.exists(saveTo)):
           try:
            ftpclient.retrbinary('RETR ' + eachFile, open(saveTo, 'wb').write)
            #logging.info('\tdownloaded '  + saveTo)
            downloaded += 1
        except BaseException as e:
            print('\terror downloading inside first %s - %s' % (eachFile, e.__str__()))
        except ftplib.error_perm:
            print('\terror downloading inside second %s - %s' % (eachFile, ftplib.error_perm))  

except Exception as e:
       print e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the destination directory `./folder/subfolder` exist?

If not you need to create it before downloading files. Either do so using your OS commands (`mkdir`), or in Python using [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) :

```
import os
try:
    os.makedirs(remotpath)
except OSError as exception:
    if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
```

You can add it somewhere before the `for` loop.

On another issue, the order of you exception handlers means that *all* exceptions raised in the inner `try` block would be handled in the `except BaseException` statement. This means that `ftplib.error_perm` will be caught in that statement because `BaseException` is more general, and not in the `ftplib.error_perm` statement as you might expect.

You should reorder your `except` statements in order of increasing generality.